# Can I intercept WinForms AxHost 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' so to avoid the Microsoft .NET error dialog

Tags: wpf, winforms, activex

We have developed a `WPF` application which enables the user to insert `ActiveX` controls dynamically using the `System.Windows.Forms.AxHost` control.
However if the user specifies a control that no longer exists or does not exist on a particular machine then we see the following dialog in `Release` mode (although we don't see the `quit` button, but only the `continue`):

[Valid XHTML http://img508.imageshack.us/img508/3898/jitps6.png](http://img508.imageshack.us/img508/3898/jitps6.png)

We would like to show the error message inline in our UI rather than the user being shown a dialog which makes it look like the application exploded.

Is there any way to intercept these exceptions so that the dialog is not shown?

Comment: Could you show us the `frmMain_Load` implementation?

Comment: I don't believe we have one of those. This is a WPF app so we create a 'System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost' (in XAML) and point it's 'Child' property at an instance of 'ActiveXWrapper' (which derives from 'System.Windows.Forms.AxHost' as it's abstract) in code-behind.

Comment: Oh, I see, your looking at the call-stack in the picture. Unfortunately that's just a link to an example pic I found on the internet.